# java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: java, java-io

I am Trying to Copy Single file from Source to Destination using Java but getting following Error message.

**`java.io.FileNotFoundException:`** Following is the method

```
public void copy_single(String source,String dest,String filename)
{
  try
  { System.out.println(source + "" + filename);
    System.out.println(dest + "" + filename);
    File inputFile = new File(source+""+filename);
    File outputFile = new File(dest+""+filename);
    Process proc0 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod -R 777 "+inputFile+"");
    proc0.waitFor();
    Process proc1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod -R 777 "+outputFile+"");
    proc1.waitFor();
    FileReader in = new FileReader(inputFile);
    FileWriter out = new FileWriter(outputFile);
    int c;
    while ((c = in.read()) != -1)
      out.write(c);
    in.close();
    out.close();
  } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Error: Operation failed!");
  }
}
```

Output:-

```
/home/root/Tool/AAputDelta.sh
/home/root/Desktop/Sqa/BaseLine/Engine/AAputDelta.sh
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/root/Desktop/Sqa/BaseLine/Engine/AAputDelta.sh (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:145)
```

How to copy simple file using java.

Comment: Did you print out and see source+""+fileName returning complete path to file?

Comment: Plese tell us the source line which is throwing the exception.

Comment: @BetaRide:   FileWriter out = new FileWriter(outputFile); throwing exception.

Comment: This means the file path of outputFile does not exist.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 10.10.and netbeans 7.2.1. When i tried to print inputFile and outputFile , It came in Red color

Comment: 1. For future questions: Can you format your code please before posting it here?  2. Please provide us with the whole exception (or at least the first few lines) you get (copy&paste).  3. For this special case: Can you do a `System.out.println(dest + "" + filename);` right at the beginning of your method and tell us the result?

Comment: @brimborium: I have updated my code with `System.out.println(dest + "" + filename);`

Comment: I think the problem is that the output file does not exist (so you can not write to it). You first have to create it. But anyway, I suggest using apache commons (like 2 of the answers suggest).

Comment: Please do not catch Exception. If you catch Exception you catch any exception (including NullPointerException and RuntimeException). Usually that is not what you want!

Comment: @brimborium No. new FileOutputStream() creates the file if necessary. See the Javadoc. You do not have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use apache commons FileUtils.  Any of these should be sufficient

```
FileUtils.copyFile(File srcFile, File destFile) 
FileUtils.copyFile(File srcFile, File destFile, boolean preserveFileDate) 
FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(File srcFile, File destDir) 
FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(File srcFile, File destDir, boolean preserveFileDate)
```

Answer (score 2):

Suspect that some or all of `dest` output path may not exist. If this is the case you could use [File.mkdirs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) to build the path.

Also, rather than building the file from strings, would suggest allowing [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) handle all this, e.g.:

```
File inputFile = new File(source, filename);
File outputFile = new File(dest, filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FileUtils from commons-io : 
http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

or the Files from Java 7 : 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

Comment: There is **always** a method in apaches commons library that does the trick. I wouldn't be surprised if they have a `HumanUtils.serverUserSomeCoffe(List<Ingredients> ingredients)`... ;)

Answer (score 0):

java.io.FileNotFoundException Means that some file was not found so check the values :

- source
- dest
- filename
- source+""+filename
- dest+""+filename

Answer (score 0):

If the file doesn't exist, the filesystem will try to create the file. If creation fails, Java will throw `FileNotFountException`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need add

```
File outputFile = new File(dest+""+filename);
if(!outputFile.exist())outputFile.createNewFile();
```

Comment: If the file can't be created by new FileOutputStream() this won't work either. Not an answer.